# Checkstyle and Findbugs for changed files only on Jenkins (and/or Hudson)

Tags: hudson, jenkins, findbugs, checkstyle

We work with a lot of legacy code and we think about introducing some metrics for new code. Is it possible to let Findbugs and Checkstyle run on changed files only instead of a complete project?

It would be nice to assure that only file with a minimum of quality is checked in, but the code base itself is not (yet) touched and evaluated not to confuse people by thousands of issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, it would be possible. You would use a shell script to parse the SVN (or whatever SCM) change logs after a given start date, identify the .java files from these change sets and build two patterns from these:

- The [Findbugs Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/) expects a comma-separated list of class (or
  package) names for the parameter [`onlyAnalyze`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/findbugs-mojo.html#onlyAnalyze), so you'll have
  to translate file names to fully qualified class names (this will get
  tricky when you're dealing with inner classes)
- The [Maven Checkstyle Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/) is even worse, it expects a
  configuration file for its [`packageNamesLocation`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/checkstyle-mojo.html#packageNamesLocation) parameter.
  Unfortunately, only packages are allowed, not individual files. So
  you'll have to translate file names to packages.

In the above examples I assume that you are using maven. I am pretty sure that similar things can be done with ant, but I wouldn't know.

I myself would probably use a Groovy script instead of a shell script to achieve the above results.

Comment: I am going to use Jenkins, Maven and GIT. Scripting too much was not really preferred. Is there a plugin, option or something already available? We can not be here the first people wanting to check just the new files.

Comment: @Rick-Rainer when you have unusual requirements, you usually have to implement them yourself. Sorry.

Comment: I though it would be that unusual... :-( Thanks for the hint, anyways. Maybe someone has a solution out of the box!?

Answer (score 2):

Findbugs has ant tasks that can do diffs against different findbugs results to see just the deltas, so only reporting new bugs, see

http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/datamining.html

Comment: Actually, that's a nice feature. One can check for new introduced bugs that way. This helps a little. I think, one can also introduce this feature into Maven somehow. I'll check this. Thanks for the hint!